# G++ compiler: option -s is obsolete and being ignored C++

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I'm trying to compile and strip a very simple program in C++ with the g++ compiler (4.6.0 on Mac OSX). But while compiling i get a warning.

---

source code:

```
#include </usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.6.0/gcc/include/c++/4.6.0/iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << ("Hello World\n") ;
}
```

Terminal code:

```
g++ hello.cc -Wall -std=c++0x -s
    /* or an alternative: */
g++ hello.cc -Wall -std=c++0x -o test -Wl,-s
```

Compiler warning:

```
ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
```

---

Somebody any idea's about this weird warning?

Edit:

The weird thing is the size **does** decrease when using the -s flag, the decreases from 9,216 bytes to 9,008.

However when i use the following the size decreases to 8,896 bytes.

```
cp hello hello_stripped
strip hello_stripped
```

Comment: Why do you want to strip the binaries? Modern systems have so much space that it seems a bit redundant to remove the information. Also diagnosing problems on a stripped binary will be practically imposable.

Comment: Why aren't you just saying `#include <iostream>` instead of the full path?

Comment: @Tux-D one reason might be that it makes it harder to reverse engineer.

Comment: - Tux-D Nice one but the reason is quite simple. Compiling, Executing and Stripping this simple program is an exercise listed in the c++ course which i enrolled. 

- Mark B, because than it will take the default iostream instead of my newly installed iostream which came with the gcc 4.6.0 compiler which is 255 bytes bigger..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is from `ld`, not from `gcc` or `g++`.  (The `gcc` and `g++` commands are drivers that invokes the compiler, the linker, and other tools.)

`gcc` passes the `-s` option to the linker, as documented in the [gcc 4.6.1 manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options); apparently the MacOS port of `gcc` still does that.

The GNU linker (GNU `ld`) still accepts the `-s` option with its usual meaning.  But the MacOS linker (also called `ld`) ignores it, as documented in the [MacOS ld manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/Xcode-3.2.5/man1/ld.1.html):

> -s  Completely strip the output, including removing the symbol table.
> This file format variant is no longer supported.  This option is
> obsolete.

And the [MacOS gcc manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/Xcode-3.2.5/man1/gcc.1.html), unlike GNU's gcc manual, doesn't mention "-s".

Comment: okay, but apparently the files get some kind of stripping according to the filesize. Does that mean the system has two linkers? GCC linker & MACOS linker ? and one thinks its an obsolete option?

Comment: @Tieme: I seriously doubt it.  The MacOS `ld` does do some kinds of stripping; it just doesn't support `-s`.  Does gcc *ever* not warn about the `-s` option?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `-s` flag is obsolete. You can use the [`strip`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/strip.1.html) program instead though.

Comment: Does that mean that symbols are (by default) still there, or already stripped?

Comment: Some information is always there unless stripped. More information is there with `-g`.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be obsolete on all systems; the gcc 4.6.1 documentation still mentions "-s".

Comment: @Keith then perhaps the message is obsolete.

Comment: Yeah, you could use the strip command but thats just another work around. I am wondering what causes the warning...

Comment: @Seth: The warning is from ld, not from gcc.  It has to do with whatever version of ld MacOS uses.  It would be worthwhile to look at the gcc and ld documentation *on MacOS*.

Comment: @Keith you should post that as the answer.